# Why are my parents telling me I'm wrong?

Tags: riddle

> Every day they look at me, they tell me I'm wrong. And I don't know why.
>   For me, it just feels like it's right.
>   Most think it's the opposite, but I've always gone the other way.
>   A crazy man once told me I'm wearing it like the devil.
>   Or maybe it's just that by chance I taught myself not to be right.
>   I'm just a disappointment when I'm dressed.

*Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?*

Comment: You're letting the patriarchy push you around.

Comment: Sounds more like a poem of an angsty goth than a riddle to me!

Comment: It's an exageration of something I remembered today that used to happen to me. Not necessarly negative (hence why it's exagerated to the limit), but a "hum.. okay then" kind of thing. The angsty goth that should rage against the machine is a method of delivery... think of it as a presentation... it's not a poem, it's a whiny weirdo ^^  (Don't take this comment as an hint, it's not)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> You wear your watch on your right wrist which is a sign that you are left-handed.
>
>  
>  tell me I'm wrong -> not right
>
>  feels like it's right -> left handed
>
>  went the other way -> right instead of left
>
>  taught myself to not be right -> left handed
>
>  doing wrong -> not right

Comment: Precisely. Albeit not being left-handed, I wear watches on the right pulse rather than on the left

Comment: Yeah I used to do that too haha

Comment: Also, lefthandedness used to be considered a sign of the devil.

Comment: Some would call it *sinister*, even.